# What is the difference between the approaches below in collections

Tags: collections

Approach one : creating object of the subclass through reference of base class.
Approach Two : creating object of the subclass through reference of same class.

```
List<Point> objOne = new ArrayList<Point>();
ArrayList<Point> objTwo = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

Answer (score 1):

List is an Interface even. It is more abstract and defines exactly but not more, the API properties. The implementation can differ in Java: ArrayList for bulk work, LinkedList for just a couple, saving on memory. This implementation decision should be hidden.

Functions should operate on List more than on a specific implementation, say ArrayList. It is also more generally formulated if one talks about Lists instead of ArrayLists. So also for variables I would not overspecify their type.

In many (scripting) languages like VB, PHP and others this distinction does not exist, and there is one type with one implementation. This simplifies their language and might appeal to some, but Java has a nice technical side.

You can play with different implementations, dynamically elect one with a factory method. Mock the implementation in a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

List is an interface while ArrayList is a Class.
So lets suppose your co-worker wrote a function which takes in a list of points and does some work on it.
Now he used abstraction like this so that his code could work on both ArrayList as well as LinkedList.

```
public void myfunction(List<Point> pointlist){
//do something on the point
}
```

Now your first object objOne will work with this function because it has used Abstraction. This is how good code should be written.

Now your second object objTwo will not work with this function and so this kind of code should be avoided.

Comment: You mean `myfunction(ArrayList...)` would not work, a good argument.

Comment: @Sanjay any other reason ?

Comment: @JoopEggen I never said that myFunction(ArrayList..) wont work. I said  it would be a bad design to have functions which have hard classes as arguments when interfaces are available.

Comment: @sanjay I expressed myself not so well, but understood.